# Direct proof that infinite product of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ is not projective

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-groups, projective-module

It is well-known that the abelian group $$A = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{Z}$$ is not free (see, for example [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10239/is-it-true-that-as-bbb-z-modules-the-polynomial-ring-and-the-power-series-r)), and that over a PID being free is equivalent to being projective (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162945/submodule-of-free-module-over-a-p-i-d-is-free-even-when-the-module-is-not-finit)), but the latter uses the axiom of choice.  Is there a direct way to see that $A$ is not projective in terms of the lifting property, ideally not using choice?

Comment: Not in terms of the lifting property, but maybe not using AC (I haven't checked the proof carefully): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64611/showing-the-countable-direct-product-of-mathbbz-is-not-projective

Comment: I am not sure that one can avoid that free and projective is equivalent for $\mathbb{Z}$-modules (and I do not see a reason to avoid it). For more references see also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90367/question-on-the-infinite-direct-product-of-projective-modules), and Jack Schmidt's remark.

Comment: You have a nice, more or less elementary, proof that $\;\Bbb Z^{\Bbb N}\;$ cannot be free abelian here:https://wildtopology.wordpress.com/2014/07/02/the-baer-specker-group/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proof that does not use the axiom of choice.  Let $e_n\in A$ denote the sequence whose $n$th term is $1$ and all other terms are $0$; we take it as known that any homomorphism $A\to\mathbb{Z}$ which vanishes on each $e_n$ is $0$ everywhere (the standard proofs of this certainly do not use choice).

Suppose $A$ were projective.  Let $F$ be the free group on the underlying set of $A$, and let $p:F\to A$ be the canonical epimorphism.  Since $A$ is projective, there is a splitting $i:A\to F$.  Now note that for each $a\in A$, there is a homomorphism $\pi_a:F\to\mathbb{Z}$ which takes a formal linear combination of elements of $A$ and gives you the coordinate of $a$.  For any $x\in F$, there are only finitely many $a\in A$ such that $\pi_a(x)\neq 0$.  In particular, there are only countably many $a\in A$ such that $\pi_a(i(e_n))\neq 0$ for some $n$.  But since $\pi_a\circ i:A\to\mathbb{Z}$ vanishes iff it vanishes on each $e_n$, this means that $\pi_a\circ i=0$ for all but countably many $a$.  This means that actually the image of $i$ is contained in the free group $G\subset F$ on a countable subset of $A$.  But this $G$ is then countable, which is a contradiction since $A$ is uncountable.

(Here I implicitly used the fact that a countable union of finite sets is countable, which requires choice in general.  However, the finite sets are finite subsets of $A$, and since it is possible to totally order $A$, we can use this to canonically biject each of the finite subsets with a finite ordinal and thus conclude that their union is countable.)

Comment: This is great; exactly the kind of thing I was looking for!